# Python executes the shell command, how to get the process ID of the process generated by the shell command

Tags: python, shell

I want to use python to execute shell commands, how to get the process ID of the process generated by the shell command.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['{}'.format(self.executor), '-c', {}'.format(config), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The process executed by this shell command does not exit by itself, I need to run 10 min to KILL it, how can I get the id of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the object `Popen` returns then use its `pid` attribute:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
print(p.pid)
```